# DjangoListField analouge for an individual object resolver

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I am using Django + GraphQL and it is extremely convenient to use `DjangoListField`. It allows me to override `get_queryset` at the `ObjectType` level and make sure all permissions verified there. In that manner I have a single place to have all my permission checks.

However, whenever I need to do something like:

```py
contract = graphene.Field(ClientContractType,
                              pk=graphene.ID(required=True))
```

I have to also duplicate permissions validation in the `resolve_contract` method. I came up with the following solution to ensure permission and avoid duplication:

```py
    def resolve_contract(self, info, pk):
        qs = ClientContract.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        return ClientContractType.get_queryset(qs, info).get()
```

It works but I'd love to have some sort of `DjangoObjectField` which will encapsulate this for me and, potentially, pass arguments to the `ClientContractType` in some way. Have someone had this problem or knows a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The best I was able to come up with is to move this logic into the `ObjectType` class, defining a method (analogues to what `DjangoObjectType` already implemented)

```py
    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, info, id):
        queryset = cls.get_queryset(cls._meta.model.objects, info)
        try:
            return queryset.get(pk=id)
        except cls._meta.model.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

then, resolver will look like

```py
    def resolve_contract(self, info, pk):
        return ClientContractType.get_node(pk)
```

Far from ideal, tho.